# SonarQube SurefireUtils error while running analysis on a project

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube, surefire, sonar-runner

I'm getting this error in Sonar Qube while running the sonar-runner on a project that contains JS,HTML,Scala,CSS.

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total time: 1:37.623s

Final Memory: 16M/639M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar

                at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)

                at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)

                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

                at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)

                at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)

                at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)

                at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)

                at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)

                at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)

                at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(Lorg/sonar/api/config/Settings;Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project;)Ljava/io/File;

                at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.analyse(SurefireSensor.java:63)

                at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)

                at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)

                at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:122)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)

                at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)

                at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)

                at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)

                at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)

                at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)

                at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)

                at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)

                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

                at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)

                ... 9 more
```

I did a bit of googling and got to know that SurefireUtils API is different depending on whether or not the Java plugin is installed and hence it throws error. I have tried a different version also but without any help.

Version Details:

Sonarqube Version : 5.0.1

Javaplugin : 2.8

Sonar-surefire : 3.3.2

I would prefer not to change the sonarqube installations and versions of other plugin. Another link on Github shows a solution to a similar problem. It didn't help me. I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a scala plugin installed ? if yes which version ?

Comment: No, I don't want to analyze Scala codes for now. I just need to analyze JS, HTML, CSS.